# terminal 'export PATH' problem

Tags: command-line, bash

Whenever I reload my terminal I see

```
export PATH    
export PATH   
(name):~$
```

I'm a noob and was messing around with bash. I need a quick fix for this.

```
$ grep PATH ~/.bashrc    
PATH=$PATH:/opt/Xilinx/14.2/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/ echo export PATH
PATH=$PATH:/opt/Xilinx/14.2/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/ echo export PATH
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `grep PATH ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

As you see, your `~/.bashrc` contains an unnecessary `echo` that prints a literal string `export PATH`.

The `~/.bashrc` file is sourced every time you start an interactive session. This is the reason why you see the string "export PATH" whenever you reload the session.

To get rid of it, just remove the `echo`. To make the command useful, replace it to a mere `export PATH` (without the leading `echo`) so that the `$PATH` variable is successfully exported as an environment variable:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/Xilinx/14.2/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/ export PATH
```

Comment: So what do I enter into the terminal?

Comment: @Carpenter edit the file `~/.bashrc` and either remove the full `echo export PATH` string or just remove the `echo` in it.